# How to remotely delete data from a Google Drive folder kept in local system

Tags: google-drive, security

Recently someone has stolen my laptop and I have some sensitive information laying in the Google Drive folder, which I am sure he/she will be able to access after opening my laptop, since it’s not password protected.

Is there any way to delete the contents of a Google Drive folder off this stolen laptop?

Comment: @pnuts well, thanks for initiative. I have changed my google account password. So, he won't be able to do further changes, since that folder's (Google drive folder from stolen lap) access has been revoked. But still, he can access all the lying data.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're pretty much screwed. If you don't have any kind of remote access to your laptop, or some sort of access, you have no way of getting in there and removing all that local data.

What you could do is back up your Google Drive folder, delete all the data from it, and hope the automatic sync will remove your data from the laptop when the perpetrator attempts to access it.

Comment: well, thanks. I have already done this. But, there is slightest chance that it'll work.

Comment: Files deleted in this way will be in the recycle bin on the local computer.